# Concentration inequality involving the ball of a fixed radius from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Let $X_1, \cdots ,X_n$ be uniformly and independently distributed points in the $m \times m$ square with $m = \sqrt{n}$ and let $Y = | \cup_i B_{X_i}(1)|$ where $B_{X}(r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ about the point $P$. Show that there exists some fixed $c >0$ such that

$$
P(| Y - \mathbf{E}(Y)| > \epsilon\sqrt{n}) \leq e^{-c\epsilon^2})
$$
$|.|$ is the cardinality of the set.

I tried to solve this as follows: since each $X_i$ are iids $Y$ is the sum of iids. My plan was to use Hoeffding's  inequality, but $X_i$s are not bounded. So I am stuck. Any help ?.
This is the second question given here https://sites.math.washington.edu/~eyal/523A/lec/hw-1.pdf.

NB:  this is an exercise for self study.

Comment: Which “iids” sum to $Y$?

Comment: What is |.| when defining $Y$?

Comment: $|.|$ is the cardinalitiy of the set.

Comment: How can  $|B|$ be the "cardinality" if $B$ is a ball (a region in space)? An why you say that $Y$ is a sum of $X$???

Comment: @leonbloy.  I found the question here. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~eyal/523A/lec/hw-1.pdf
It is the second question.  I guessed $|.|$ is the cardinality of the $X_i$ s contained in the ball.  Since $X_i$ are iids, I assumed that the number of $X_i$ in the unit ball is also iids